# 'Cross Origin' error message resulting from local XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using AJAX to display upcoming events on a website. To that end, I call a JavaScript function via onload="showEvents(3);", see the function below:

```
function showEvents (amount) {

    // are there Events?
    if (document.getElementById("eventsDiv")) {

        document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].innerHTML = 'Loading events...';

        // initialize XML Http Request
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("eventsDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        // send request
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "./events.php?number=" + encodeURIComponent(amount), true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

}
```

The file events.php is a PHP file in the same directory, and it connects to the database to fetch the upcoming events. The HTML header of the main website includes

```
<base href="http://www.my-domain.com/">
```

The problem: I get a "Cross Orign" error message (in Firefox), preventing my parent index.html file accessing the events.php. As I understand, this error message should not appear since I am using a resource from the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that's ok, you also can do like this...

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == "http://your-domain.com") {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-domain.com');
```